# Rails 3 datatypes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

Where can I find a list of data types that can be used in rails 3? (such as text, string, integer, float, date, etc.?) I keep randomly learning about new ones, but I'd love to have a list I could easily refer to.

Answer (score 270, accepted):

Here are all the `Rails3` (ActiveRecord migration) datatypes:

:binary
:boolean
:date
:datetime
:decimal
:float
:integer
:primary_key
:references
:string
:text
:time
:timestamp

[Source](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column)

Comment: and :references for polymorphic associations.  See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html

Comment: the guide has changed. Maybe a link to the relevant documentation should replace it.

Comment: @HarryMoreno: Thanks for the tip! I updated the reference, please let me know if you find any better one.

Comment: References is not limited to polymorphic associations. And i would not count it as a datatype.

Answer (score 67):

It is important to know not only the types but the mapping of these types to the database types, too:

[image]

[image]

For, example, note that in MS SQL Server we are using:

1. the old "datetime" instead "datetime2"
2. decimal with its default precision
3. text and varchar instead nvarchar
4. int (not possible to use tiny int/small int/big int)
5. image instead BLOB

Comment: As find from [this blog](http://ariejan.net/2009/08/20/once-and-for-all-rails-migrations-integer-limit-option/).  

The tinyint/smallint/bigint can be set by using :limit option with :integer.  

I have tested it on Rails 3 and MySQL, they are still working, just as said in the blog, they are signed integer.

Answer (score 26):

Do you mean for defining active record migrations? or do you mean Ruby data types?

Here's a link that may help for creating migrations:

[Orthogonal Thought - MySQL and Ruby on Rails datatypes](http://www.orthogonalthought.com/blog/index.php/2007/06/mysql-and-ruby-on-rails-datatypes/)

Answer (score 15):

It might be helpful to know generally what these data types are used for:

- binary - is for storing data such as images, audio, or movies.
- boolean - is for storing true or false values.
- date - store only the date
- datetime - store the date and time into a column.
- decimal - is for decimals.
- float - is for decimals. ([What's the difference between decimal and float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514167/float-vs-decimal-in-activerecord))
- integer - is for whole numbers.
- primary_key - unique key that can uniquely identify each row in a table
- string - is for small data types such as a title. ([Should you choose string or text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354330/difference-between-string-and-text-in-rails))
- text - is for longer pieces of textual data, such as a paragraph of information.
- time - is for time only
- timestamp - for storing date and time into a column.

I hope that helps someone! Also, here's the official list: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#supported-types