# Why is my floating point rounded in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, floating-point, rails-activerecord

I have a model that uses floating points to store geolocations. It stores the data in MySQL, using ActiveRecord, Rails 3.2.x.

```
c = Camping.new()
c.latitude=51.77802459999999
c.save
c.latitude
=> 51.77802459999999
c.reload
c.latitude
=> 51.778
```

When looking in the database, I confirm it is stored as 51.778. Other numbers are stored with more precision, I have the idea the `0` is what makes either ActiveRecord or MySQL decide to omit the rest.

What decides that the number could or should be chopped off after three digits? Is there anything to control this? Is float the correct type to store this in?

I want a precision of 6, never more, but could be less, or padded. So when `51.7780` is provided, it might be stored as `51.7780` or as `51.778000`. When `51.77802459999999`is provided, it could be stored as `51.778025` or as the number with full precision; I don't really care.

Relevant part from `schema.rb`:

```
  create_table "campings", :force => true do |t|
    #...
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
  end
```

Comment: What database,  and what is the attribute type for latitude?

Comment: Can you post your `schema.rb` snippet the campings_table code.

Comment: Database, as stated is MySQL. I will post the schema in a sec.

Comment: try double instead of float

Comment: @RadBrad: double is not an AR type, AFAIK. integer or decimal is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, MySQL is the problem, as float is described as an [approximated value](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/floating-point-types.html).

You can use decimal instead, and specify the precision and scale:

```
create_table "campings", :force => true do |t|
  #...
  t.decimal    "latitude",  :precision => 15, :scale => 10
  t.decimal    "longitude", :precision => 15, :scale => 10
end
```

Comment: Are there any downsides in storage- and lookuptime, indexing or storage-space there? For my smallscale app it won't matter the least bit; but just for clarity.

Comment: according to [High Performance MySQL](http://www.amazon.com/High-Performance-MySQL-Optimization-Replication/dp/1449314287) float points are [faster](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BL0NNoFPuAQC&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83#v=onepage&q&f=false). However, they are not reliable, so I believe the small improvement in performance does not worth it.

Comment: Comparison and bench-marking : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514167/float-vs-decimal-in-activerecord