# Does Ruby Round or Truncate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Ruby on Rails 4.2.3. If I store a number that has five decimal places in a database field that only allows two decimal places, is the number truncated or automagically rounded?

Does 10.12565 become 10.12 or 10.13?

The database field types for both are decimal data types.

Comment: It depends on your database. Isn't it easier just to check it yourself?

Comment: Ruby does nothing in that case. Your database does the thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Float vs Decimal in ActiveRecord](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514167/float-vs-decimal-in-activerecord)

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Postgres is the database

Comment: I didn't realize it was the database that handles this. It looks like Postgres rounds.Sorry for the trivial question. :)

Comment: Based on a very simple script it looks like postgres will round when the value scale exceeds the column scale

Comment: Are you sure it is rounding not truncating? Have you checked the PostgreSQL documentation to see what behavior is specified? Don't trust empirical evidence unless you're willing to check all boundary conditions and special cases and even then things can change during an upgrade unless the behavior is specified.

Comment: If you're really concerned about this, why not write unit tests to verify you're getting the correct behaviour? There's a dozen ways to round numbers, each with various benefits and drawbacks, so ensuring you're using the correct one is a simple process, but a necessary one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-numeric.html

In section: 8.1.2. Arbitrary Precision Numbers

They will automatically round:

> If the scale of a value to be stored is greater than the declared
>   scale of the column, the system will round the value to the specified
>   number of fractional digits. Then, if the number of digits to the left
>   of the decimal point exceeds the declared precision minus the declared
>   scale, an error is raised.

I would suggest setting your database to the expected result for that field using: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-math.html

Then writing unit tests to ensure you are getting the intended results.