# How to properly generate model table for float with specific precision and scale?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to generate table with `float` data type similar to this `decimal` table.

```
add_column :table_name, :lat, :decimal, {:precision=>10, :scale=>6}
```

How do I do that properly ? And what would terminal command look like for `rails generate model`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decimal is better than Float.

You can find why here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

And in this other SO post:

[Float vs Decimal in ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514167/float-vs-decimal-in-activerecord)

So for me.. your first approach is correct. Use decimal with precision.

BTW i think rails does not support :float with :precision.

Comment: This answer is very incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

The correct is 'price:decimal{5,2}' or price:decimal{5-2}

```
rails generate migration AddDetailsToProducts 'price:decimal{5,2}'
```

as pointed out [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13520#issuecomment-370100231)