# Why can't I set precision and scale for float in rails migration?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

After I run this migration, my geo_latitude and geo_longitude columns are type "float" (no precision and scale). I can run sql query directly and change the type to float(10, 6), so why does the migration ignore my precision and scale parameters?

```
def change
  add_column :item_exifs, :geo_latitude, :float, precision: 10, scale: 6, null: false, default: 0
  add_column :item_exifs, :geo_longitude, :float, precision: 10, scale: 6, null: false, default: 0
end
```

Comment: why not use decimal ?, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514167/float-vs-decimal-in-activerecord

Comment: @icemelt because I don't need to be too precise of the location, and float is faster to do calculation. And I'm just curious if this is bug in migration or is it intended?

Comment: see @rokibul hasan answer, he have problems with mysql and float and change it to decimal fix it for him, maybe also for you.

Comment: @icemelt Maybe that's the only option :) thank you

Comment: ok I change my comment into answer then.

Answer (score 3):

try to change the type to decimal,

```
def change
  add_column :item_exifs, :geo_latitude, :decimal, precision: 10, scale: 6, null: false, default: 0
  add_column :item_exifs, :geo_longitude, :decimal, precision: 10, scale: 6, null: false, default: 0
end
```

some active record versions have several strange behavior based on the databases used

[Float vs Decimal in ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514167/float-vs-decimal-in-activerecord)

see @Rokibul Hasan and @ryan0 answers