# How to apply "to_f" to a column for all results in an active record query inside rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this query:
`p = Payment.where(:client_id => 1)`

Then only some fields, so I execute this:
`p.select(:id, :created_at, :amount)`

The issue is that every amount in the result comes as BigDecimal, and it's not readable. I need to apply `to_f` function inside rails console to have a readable set of results.

I tried `map`,like this:
`p.map {|p| p.amount.to_f}`
But it returns to me an array only with the amounts, and I need it to be along with the other attributes.

Comment: Payment.where(:client_id => 1).select([:id,:created_at,:amount]).map {|e| [e.id, e.created_at, e.amount.to_f] }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
p.map { |item| { id: item.id, created_at: item.created_at, amount: item.amount.to_f}}
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve you problem and get all fields:

```
p.map { |i| [i.id, i.created_at, i.amount.to_f] }
```

Also you can take a look on this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514167/float-vs-decimal-in-activerecord). Maybe you just need float type for `amount` field in your DB

Answer (score 0):

if you always want `float` of amount you can set callback `after_find`

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_find do |payment|
    self.amount = self.amount.to_f
  end
end
```

it will always give you float value when you find object

- It will not update value in your db.

Please Look on this [Rails Callback](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html)

Comment: I need to do this inside the rails console. That seems a lot of code to put in the console, compared with `https://stackoverflow.com/users/5954643/rajkumar-ulaganadhan` solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: it will work on your console too, i mean you will get same output.