# Create sql procedure but it's not appeared in the table

Tags: mysql

there is no error but also doesn't show success

at first, it shows on only table registrations and not the registration_details, and now doesn't appear in both table.

```
set foreign_key_checks = 0;
drop procedure if exists createRegist;

delimiter //

create procedure createRegist()
begin
    declare total_credit float;
    declare registration_id INT;
    declare credit float;
    
    -- create first registration for student 1
    set total_credit = 0;
    insert into `student_regist`.`registrations` (`registration_id`, `student_id`,`total_credit`)
        values (1, 1, total_credit);
    
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO registration_id;
     
    -- create registration detail 1
SELECT 
    `student_regist`.`courses`.`credit`
INTO credit FROM
    `student_regist`.`courses`
WHERE
    `student_regist`.`courses`.`course_id` = 1
LIMIT 1;
    set total_credit = total_credit + credit;
    insert into `student_regist`.`registration_details` (`registration_details_id`, `registration_id`, `course_id`, `semester`) 
        values (1, 1, 1, 1);

    SELECT 'Success';
end//

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided nearly enough detail for us to provide any concrete answers. Adding the DDL for your tables to your question is the minimum required for a real answer.

That said, here are some suggestions.

We know nothing of the values you need to store in `credit` (and `total_credit`) but it seems likely that it should be `DECIMAL`, and not `FLOAT`. Searching [decimal vs float](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=decimal+vs+float) on here returns [Float vs Decimal in ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514167/float-vs-decimal-in-activerecord) as the first result.

If you are using MySQL Workbench the errors/warnings should be displayed in the Output Area (View -> Panels -> Show Output Area). Or you could run `SHOW WARNINGS;` after calling your SP.

```
CALL createRegist();
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

Your first insert into `registrations` uses a hardcoded value of 1 for `registration_id`, which is presumably the primary key (PK) for the table. The second time you execute the SP and it tries to insert 1 into your PK, it will fail with a duplicate key error -

```
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '1' for key 'registrations.PRIMARY'
```

You then follow up with the call for `LAST_INSERT_ID()` which will not work as you are expecting. From the MySQL docs -[LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

> The value of LAST_INSERT_ID() is not changed if you set the AUTO_INCREMENT column of a row to a non-“magic” value (that is, a value that is not NULL and not 0).

Changing the value passed in the insert statement to NULL or 0 (or removing completely) will resolve this -

```
/* Passing in value of NULL */
set total_credit = 0;
insert into `student_regist`.`registrations` (`registration_id`, `student_id`,`total_credit`)
    values (NULL, 1, total_credit);

/* or removing completely */
set total_credit = 0;
insert into `student_regist`.`registrations` (`student_id`,`total_credit`)
    values (1, total_credit);
```