# What is the difference between the Rails datatypes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I know that Rails datatypes can be found here:

[Rails 4: List of available datatypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918117/rails-4-datatypes)

or here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column

but what I can't find is a clear definition of each, and the differences between, say, a float versus a decimal, or a string versus text.

Where can I find in-depth definitions of the datatypes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a good set of definitions (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15316528/2128691)

- binary - is for storing data such as images, audio, or movies.
- boolean - is for storing true or false values.
- date - store only the date
- datetime - store the date and time into a column.
- decimal - is for decimals.
- float - is for decimals. ([What's the difference between decimal and float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514167/float-vs-decimal-in-activerecord))
- integer - is for whole numbers.
- primary_key - unique key that can uniquely identify each row in a table
- string - is for small data types such as a title. ([Should you choose string or text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354330/difference-between-string-and-text-in-rails))
- text - is for longer pieces of textual data, such as a paragraph of information.
- time - is for time only
- timestamp - for storing date and time into a column.

Comment: You forgot numeric, bigint, binary...

Answer (score 2):

Rails is built on the Ruby language, so try searching for Ruby datatypes instead!

http://www.rubybacon.com/ruby-data-types/ (link no longer working)

**Updated link**

http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/built_in_classes.html

Comment: This link is dead as of June 2016.