# Rails 4 oracle enhanced adapter matching number(1) fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, ruby-on-rails-3.2, oracle11g, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `legacy db` on which I am building a `rails 4` app.

In my *db schema* there are quite some fields that have single digit non boolean numbers (like 1-9) where a data-type of `Number(1)` was used. However, the oracle adapter automatically assumes that data-type `number(1)` is always boolean.

As can be seen in this question (rails3 aside 4 seems to be the same) [Rails 3 datatypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685009/rails-3-datatypes)

I have tried to find an option for that on the o.e.a. github page however I could not find one.

A pointer in the right direction would be great.

Comment: I don't think that is a correct behaviour - to presume that every one-number column is a boolean. I'd say go ahead and create an issue on their github page. I'm sure they'll at least give you a workaround.

Comment: Good to try: https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/tree/rails4

Comment: @Magnuss actually it is default behavior https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/issues/338

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/issues/338

This is a default behavior also you can disable if you want.

https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/blob/master/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb#L109-L117

```
  ##
  # :singleton-method:
  # By default, the OracleEnhancedAdapter will consider all columns of type <tt>NUMBER(1)</tt>
  # as boolean. If you wish to disable this emulation you can add the following line
  # to your initializer file:
  #
  #   ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::OracleEnhancedAdapter.emulate_booleans = false
  cattr_accessor :emulate_booleans
  self.emulate_booleans = true
```

Comment: Well, at least it's easy to turn it off.