# ActiveRecord with SQL Server 2008R2 sees decimal(18,2) column as decimal(18,0)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, activerecord

We use Rails 3.2.18 with activerecord-sqlserver-adapter gem. Everything was fine until we noticed an issue that decimal column is treated as integer. Tuns out that despite the fact that column has decimal(18,2) type set, ActiveRecords sees it as decimal(18,0), and treats attribute as integer.

```
> Model.columns_hash['decimal_attr'].sql_type
=> "decimal(18,0)"

> Model.columns_hash['decimal_attr'].type
=> :integer
```

Any suggestions? I'd be happy to get at least a direction to dig this.

**Edit:** this is an existing table in a legacy database

Comment: Mapping from SQL Server should be decimal to decimal - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685009/rails-3-datatypes. I suggest have a look at default values http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column and if necessary overwrite.

Comment: @PavelNefyodov, unfortunately this is an existing table in legacy database, I cannot recreate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in case someone will stumble upon same issue here is a quick hack I came up with. After model has been saved a simple UPDATE query is issued as raw SQL. This does not solve the issue, but allows legacy app that uses the same db to get decimal(18,2) value. Here is a code for a query:

```
value = ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(@value)
query = "UPDATE [models] SET [attribute] = #{value} WHERE [models].[id] = #{@model.id}"
Property.connection.execute(query)
```