# smallint is not working to genrate model and table rails 3+ postgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, mode

first I have run this command

```
rails generate model FeedbackComment type:smallint reply:text
```

after then

```
rake db:migrate
```

I am getting this error

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `smallint' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::TableDefinition:0x9d1a318>/var/www/blog/db/migrate/20140712064127_create_feedback_comments.rb:4:in `block in change'
```

How can i create smallint through command in postgreSQL ?

Please hellp me

Comment: There is no `smallint` datatype that supports `Rails`.Give `integer` datatype with `limit`.

Comment: Like this `rails generate model FeedbackComment type:integer{2} reply:text`.`2 bytes of integer` is a `smallint`.

Comment: Do you got any error?

Comment: SyntaxError: /var/www/blog/db/migrate/20140712071128_create_users.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
      t.smallint{2} :reply_type

Comment: Can you post the command,how you gave it?

Comment: ails generate model User reply_type:smallint{2} reply:text

Comment: I said give like this `rails generate model FeedbackComment type:integer{2} reply:text`. `integer` not `smallint`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As I said,there is no `smallint` that supports **Rails 3**.You should be using `integer datatype` with `limit of 2 bytes` to make it as `smallint`.

For a list of available **Rails 3 datatypes**,see this **[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685009/rails-3-datatypes)** Post.

This command will give you what you want

```
rails generate model FeedbackComment type:integer{2} reply:text
```

See this **[link](http://railsguides.net/advanced-rails-model-generators/)** for advanced Rails model generators.

Here is some more useful info

```
:limit     Numeric Type  Column Size    Max value
1          tinyint       1 byte         127
2          smallint      2 bytes        32767
3          mediumint     3 bytes        8388607
nil, 4, 11 int(11)       4 bytes        2147483647
5..8       bigint        8 bytes        9223372036854775807
```

Answer (score 4):

The way of adding PostgreSQL `smallint` data type in Rails 6, 5, and 4 is still the same, an integer data type with limit 2.

```
class AddColumnNameToTableName < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_column :table_name, :column_name, :integer, limit: 2
  end
end
```

`# => column_name smallint`.