# Parsing html to string and vice versa in Rails app

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am in the middle of implementing a text editor in my Rails app.
My text editor only outputs html. When I'm saving it to my database, I need to stringify it. And when I load the text from my database it needs to parse stringified html to normal html.

```
1) parse html -> stringified html
2) parse stringified html -> html
```

How can I do this in Rails app?

Comment: Why not store the HTML?

Comment: Can you save HTML in postgres database? I don't think there is a suck thing like that

Comment: Yeah, in a TEXT field. HTML is simply text with a structure.

Comment: How is TEXT field different than normal STRING field?

Comment: The size you can store. Strings are usually limited, I believe around 256, but that my be from older days. Text, might be able to hold a couple GB. See the documentation on the database you are using to know the exact numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using a `text` type to store your html. Assuming you're storing it in a column called `content`, I would display it as such:

```
#controller
def show
  @model = Model.find(params[:id])
end

#view
<%= @model.content.html_safe %>
```

This will render content as HTML instead of printing tags.

Comment: When I save the HTML, it seems like i need to save HTML as TEXT type. How is it different than STRING type?

Comment: Most databases limit `string` character maximums to 255, but a `text` can have up to 4,294,967,296 characters. See more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354330/difference-between-string-and-text-in-rails

Comment: when I save HTML to database, should I still save it as String format: "<h1>sample</h1>" ? I tried without quotation mark and it's not working. And even if I put html output in quotation mark, it gives me an error on bracket.

Comment: Yes, still use quotations. Rails String variables are different than a database string datatype. When using `text` datatype, we mean when you generated the database model you would use `$ rails generate model ModelName content:text` as a part of your command line model generation.

Comment: That's exactly I did. When I try to save html in quotation mark under TEXT type, it gives me an error on brackets (like <>) saying `syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting end-of-input`

Comment: What error do you get without quotation marks?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117144/discussion-between-okomikeruko-and-johksi).

Comment: Hello, quick question. how did you get html code from the editor when you are using Froala? I am having hard time with it. Did you get it from the uI (editor) itself or did you call an API method?

Comment: According to the Froala API, I added the gem to the Gemfile, ran `bundle install`, added a CSS id to a form text_area_tag, then on page load ran some jQuery `$('textarea#wysiwyg').froalaEditor();` It automatically converts the output to HTML.